# Thread.CurrentPrincipal is authenticated but ClaimsPrincipal.Current is not

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-4.5, identity, claims-based-identity

I'm using Claims based Authorization in my WebApi project and have a method where I check if the current Identity is authenticated. When I use `ClaimsPrincipal.Current` the current Identity is not authenticated but when I use `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` it is.

```
ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity.IsAuthenticated; //False
Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.IsAuthenticated; //True
```

This seems strange especially since the [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal.current.aspx)  ClaimsPrincipal.Current just returns Thread.CurrentPrincipal:

> **Remarks**
>
> By default, Thread.CurrentPrincipal is returned. You can change this
>   behavior by setting the ClaimsPrincipalSelector property to specify a
>   delegate to be called to determine the current principal.

Can someone please explain me why `ClaimsPrincipal` is not authenticated, while both, in theory, contain the same Identity?

Comment: "By default, " implies to me that some other behaviour is possible - have you ruled that our?

Comment: No the ClaimsPrincipalSelector is null, so the default is used.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In short, the documentation is incorrect to say that it returns `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` by default.

What it actually returns is a `ClaimsPrincipal` *wrapping* `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` (if it's not, actually, already a `ClaimsPrincipal`), using this constructor:

```
public ClaimsPrincipal(IPrincipal principal)
{
    this.m_version = "1.0";
    this.m_identities = new List<ClaimsIdentity>();
    if (principal == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("principal");
    }
    ClaimsPrincipal principal2 = principal as ClaimsPrincipal;
    if (principal2 == null)
    {
        this.m_identities.Add(new ClaimsIdentity(principal.Identity));
    }
    else if (principal2.Identities != null)
    {
        this.m_identities.AddRange(principal2.Identities);
    }
}
```

This, in turn, as you can hopefully see, is returning a `ClaimsIdentity` that *wraps* the principal's identity (again, if it's not, actually, already a `ClaimsIdentity`).

In constructing the `ClaimsIdentity`, the only place I can see where it will end up not setting the authentication type (and thus creating an identity that's not authenticated) is here:

```
if(identity is WindowsIdentity)
{
   try
   {
      this.m_authenticationType = identity.AuthenticationType;
   }
   catch(UnauthorizedAccessException)
   {
      this.m_authenticationType = null;
   }
}
```

So, *if* the identity you access via `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity` is actually a `WindowsIdentity` instance, and in the context in which you're running you've got restricted permissions, the constructed `ClaimsIdentity` instance will have `IsAuthenticated` as false.

Comment: Thread.CurrentPrincipal contains a ClaimsPrincipal in my code. From the code you posted I see that a List is build, but it doesn't explain to me why IsAuthenticated is set to false. Is it for example because ClaimsPrincipal does some additional validation which fails? I did like to know why it is false so I can either fix what fails or set the claimsprincipal to authenticated knowing why it is false in the first place.

Comment: @JosVinke - If it's a `ClaimsPrincipal` already, then all of the above is moot, since it should just be returning the same instance. Is `ReferenceEquals(ClaimsPrincipal.Current,Thread.CurrentPrincipal)` true?

Comment: It returns false indeed, the difference is that ClaimsPrincipal.Current is a System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal and Thread.CurrentPrincipal is Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal. But I still wonder why it is set to false.

Comment: @JosVinke - in that case, you're mixing older WIF code and newer (baked into the core) Framework identity code. So it's likely to be doing some of the wrapping I described above.

Comment: I ran into a descrepency between Thread.CurrentPrincipal and ClaimsPrincipal.Current as well.  In my case the issue was our use of Windows authentication but with a process that added local claims from the database.  The resulting ClaimsPrincipal.Current was a RolePrincipal, but because RolePrincipal overrides the Identity it was looking for claims from it's own Identity instead of from the base ClaimsPrincipal's Identity.  The solution was to set the ClaimsPrincipalSelector to always return a new ClaimsPrincipal based upon the existing Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.