# HttpActionContext.RequestContext.Principal weird behavior

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

The below code is in a common place, so that all my WebAPI projects will use this filter.
But the problem is it's working for some project's and not working from some projects.

I have tried to debug and came to know that for working projects the `actionContext.RequestContext.Principal` is of type `System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal` and for not working projects it is coming as `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity` I am not sure what is causing this problem.
I am using WebAPI 2.2 with .Net Framework 4.5.2

```
public class CustomAuthenticationAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        //Some Logic
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: In those working projects do you find any configuration explicitly setting WindowsPrincipal to the Thread? Also the last lines in accepted answer from [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341966/thread-currentprincipal-is-authenticated-but-claimsprincipal-current-is-not) may give you some clue.

Comment: What is your need ? To know if the user is authenticated, or if the user is authorized to access a method (ie, blongs to a specific LDAP group) ?